# Proper Hagba Procedure: Text Facing Table?

Tags: minhag, simchat-torah, hagbah-gelilah

I recently was asked to be a magbiah. Before I came to the bimah, the chazzan turned the scroll so that the text was facing down (toward the table). So, when I grasped the atzey chaim and lifted it, the text was facing towards the ark and then I needed to turn around so that the text was facing toward the congregation. Is this a minhag in some (ashkenazi) shuls? It seemed a bit odd to me.

Comment: I have never seen this minhag. What kind of shul was it?

Comment: Was this the _V'zos hab'racha_ scroll on _Simchas Tora_?

Comment: It was during Maariv on Simchat Torah. It was an Orthodox Ashkenazi shul. Is this something that happens during Simchat Torah only?

Comment: @eliyahu12 We never read the Torah at night, (never from an actual Torah, and even just reading Tanach without learning it is generally prohibited at night.) So why were they doing hagbah at night?

Comment: @user613 Most Ashkenazi congregations read from the Torah on Simchas Torah night after Maariv. Reading Tanakh is never prohibited (except Tisha B'Av and Shiva).

Answer (score 7):

As indicated by msh210, it is a common custom on *Simchas Torah* to turn the *Sefer Torah* outwards when doing *Hagbah* after reading *V'zos habrachah* (the very end of the Pentateuch), and some do it for *B'reishis Bara* (The beginning) and *Maftir* (the day's offerings) too. Some *Ashkenazim* do it both by night and by day, some only in the morning, and some not at all.<sup>1</sup>

As for the reasons:<sup>2</sup>

1. *Pirkei Avos* 5:26: "Turn the Torah over and over for everything is in it."
2. A symbol of turning back the *Torah* to the beginning. (The last letter is **ל** and the first is **ב**, indicating that the entirety should be held together by the heart, **לב**.)

---

Sources:

1. Experience.
2. [An Encyclopedia of American Synagogue Ritual](http://books.google.ca/booksid=1AnLLpbX3XMC&pg=PA62)

Comment: Although the practice is as you mention, I've never seen anyone flip it upside down first, it is always an akward process of crossing ones arms over each other mid-air.

Comment: @user6591 Indeed flipping it is probably prohibited, YD 277

Comment: @user6591 I saw it done this year. The empty eitz was lifted over the full one and put down on the other side, thus effectively turning the sefer upside down.

Comment: @adam Unfortunately, seeing it done doesn't prove it's not asur.