# Changing Hagba During Simchas Torah?

Tags: minhag, simchat-torah, hagbah-gelilah

How can [allusions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47436/13811) to like "turn the Torah over because it's all in it" - הֲפֹךְ בָּהּ וַהֲפֹךְ בָּהּ, דְּכֹלָּא בָהּ [[Avos 5:22]](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.22?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) justify putting the Torah at greater risk of falling or tearing by changing hagba on Simchas Torah where the writing faces outwards?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77136/what-is-the-origin-of-the-reverse-hagbah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47406/proper-hagba-procedure-text-facing-table

Comment: @Alex thank you for finding that for me - though I'm still not sure why the answer in the post justifies a risky hagba, I really appreciate you finding the post!

Comment: Doesn't every time the Torah is lifted put it at risk of falling? It's often difficult and you need to be careful during Hagbah, now it's just a bit more difficult and you need to be a bit more careful during Hagbah.

Comment: I doubt there's that much additional risk, relatively speaking.

Comment: @Salmononius2 In my experience, there is significantly more wobbling and jerky movements (along with at least two gabbaim ready to grab the sefer Torah) even with stronger individuals. It seems the difference in difficulty is not so much between a 6 and a 7 but more of a 5 and 8 - hence the question

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're asking why it's done (which is what the start of your post sounds like) or how it can be justified (which is what the end if you're post sounds like). Please clarify with an [edit] so this doesn't get answers you're not seeking.